# How do I stop chrome from HTML encoding question mark when testing a website locally?

Tags: google-chrome, query-string

I am testing a website locally(just using the html file, not serving it).
I have some js that setting something using a query string and currently Chrome is HTML ending the question mark into  '%3F' so the ulr bars says `registration.html%3Ftesting=true` so I'm getting `Your file was not found`. How do I get chrome to stop html  encoding the question mark?